# Is there a shortcut for creating fields / properties from constructor inputs? (c#)

Tags: c#

Say you have a constructor in a newly created class:

```
public MyClass( string input1, float input2)
{
}
```

Is there a shortcut to produce code analogous to this?

```
public string Input1 {get; set;}
public float Input2 {get; set;}

public MyClass(string input1, float input2)
{
    Input1 = input1;
    Input2 = input2;
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Not yet. Wait until C# 6 comes out.

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that visual studio helps you out abit.

It works when the constructtor doesnt exist yet.

Just type:

```
SomeClass a = new SomeClass(input1, input2);
```

It will be underlined red as the constructor doesnt exist yet.
Then Rightclick on the not yet existing Constructor and Click

Generate => Construcotr

The result will look like this:

```
string input1;
float input2;

public SomeClass(string input1, float input2)
{
    // Some comment i dont remember
    this.input1 = input1;
    this.input2 = input2;
}
```

**edit** It is possible, that this feature only exists in Premium / Ultimate edition. Not sure on that one.

Comment: Worked for me with VS Professional 2013

Answer (score 1):

Considering the fields (they are properties really) are public in your example, you don't actually need a constructor. You can initialize them when you construct a new instance:

```
var x = new SomeClass { input1 = "value1", input2 = 12345 };
```